# How to set UIView height dynamic using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

In my case, I am trying to create multiple views inside main `UIView` scrollview. Here, If I remove or add particular view in main view. I need to auto adjust main view `height`. I tried using `storyboard` but cant able to achieve it.

For example I need to remove `green` view based on that `orange` view height auto adjust.

**Storyboard Constraints**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The recommended (and best) approach is to have a "contentView" inside the Scroll View. Please check this tutorial about Scroll Views: https://medium.com/@pradeep_chauhan/how-to-configure-a-uiscrollview-with-auto-layout-in-interface-builder-218dcb4022d7